# Compactness of $C[J,X]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, compactness, compact-operators

If $J=[0,T]\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $X$ is a Banach space? Then, is $C[J,X]$ (Banach space of all continuous functions from $J$ to $X$) a compact metric space with respect to supnorm defined as $\|x\|_{\infty}=\sup \{x(t): t\in[0,T]\}$?

Comment: I don't think so. Any compact metric space is separable, and $C[J,X]$ is not necessarily separable.

Comment: Its not even true for $J=[0,1]$ and $X=\mathbb{R}$:
The sequence $f_n=x^n$ is bounded by $||f_n|| \leq 1$, but has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: No nontrivial normed space is compact. So except in the trivial situation where $X = \{0\}$, the space you wrote down is never compact. Though, of course, it is a Banach space, so it’s complete.

Answer (score 4):

The only normed space that is compact is $\{0\}$. Any other Banach space is unbounded (as soon as $x\ne0$, $\|nx\|$ can be made arbitrarily large for $n\in\mathbb N$), so not compact.

Answer (score 1):

No unbounded metric space can be compact. In particular $C(X,Y)$ is not compact when $Y$ is not bounded. Just pick a sequence of constant functions, with unbounded values. And every normed space is unbounded, except for the zero space.

But even if both $X$ and $Y$ are compact, $C(X,Y)$ does not have to be. Consider $X=Y=[0,1]$ and the sequence $f_n(t)=t^n$.